# QGraphicsScene ignores Stretches of Grid Layout

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qsizepolicy

I have a Widget that divides into two subwidgets. One shows a picture, the other one offers options to edit the picture. The picture subwidget should take 5 times the horizontal space than the edit subwidget. I specify this constraint in a Grid Layout. However, the constraint is ignored as soon as I add a QGraphicsScene (and View) to the edit subwidget.

I tried several size policies, but none of them did what I wanted, however I am not too experienced using those.

```
class MapWidget(QWidget):
""" Widget that renders the map and displays properties """
    def __init__(self, main_gui, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent=parent)
        self.main_gui = main_gui

        # (Re-)Build the ui
        self.layout = QGridLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

        self.map_scene = QGraphicsScene()
        self.map_scene_view = QGraphicsView()
        self.map_scene_view.setViewport(QGLWidget())
        self.map_scene_view.setScene(self.map_scene)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.map_scene_view, 1, 1, 5, 1)

        blocks_container = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addLayout(blocks_container, 1, 2, 1, 1)

        """
        Here I add other widgets to the blocks_container, 
        however none of those causes problems
        """

        # As soon as I also add this group, both widgets have the same size 
        group_blocks = QGroupBox('Blocks')
        self.blocks_scene = QGraphicsScene()
        self.blocks_scene_view = QGraphicsView()
        self.blocks_scene_view.setViewport(QGLWidget())
        self.blocks_scene_view.setScene(self.blocks_scene)
        group_blocks_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        group_blocks.setLayout(group_blocks_layout)
        group_blocks_layout.addWidget(self.blocks_scene_view)
        blocks_container.addWidget(group_blocks)
```

Instead of having the two widgets with ratios 5/6 and 1/6, both widgets share the same size, which makes the picture look small and the edit widget too big. Also, once I remove the 'group_blocks' widget, the edit subwidget has its proper size again. For simplicity I therefore excluded all the other widgets it contains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it and adjust as you need:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore    import *
from PyQt5.QtGui     import *
from PyQt5.QtOpenGL  import *

class MapWidget(QWidget):
    """ Widget that renders the map and displays properties """

    def __init__(self, main_gui="???", parent=None):          # main_gui="???"
        super().__init__(parent=parent)
        self.main_gui = main_gui

        # (Re-)Build the ui
        self.layout = QGridLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

        self.map_scene = QGraphicsScene()
        self.map_scene_view = QGraphicsView()
        self.map_scene_view.setViewport(QGLWidget())
        self.map_scene_view.setScene(self.map_scene)

#        self.layout.addWidget(self.map_scene_view, 1, 1, 5, 1)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.map_scene_view, 1, 1, 5, 5)

        blocks_container = QVBoxLayout()

#        self.layout.addLayout(blocks_container, 1, 2, 1, 1)
        self.layout.addLayout(blocks_container, 1, 6, 5, 1)

        self.layout.setColumnMinimumWidth(1, 320)              # +++
        self.layout.setRowMinimumHeight(1, 200)                # +++
        self.layout.setColumnStretch(1, 5)                     # +++
        self.layout.setColumnStretch(6, 1)                     # +++

        """
        Here I add other widgets to the blocks_container, 
        however none of those causes problems
        """

        # As soon as I also add this group, both widgets have the same size 
        group_blocks = QGroupBox('Blocks')
        self.blocks_scene = QGraphicsScene()
        self.blocks_scene_view = QGraphicsView()
        self.blocks_scene_view.setViewport(QGLWidget())
        self.blocks_scene_view.setScene(self.blocks_scene)
        group_blocks_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        group_blocks.setLayout(group_blocks_layout)
        group_blocks_layout.addWidget(self.blocks_scene_view)
        blocks_container.addWidget(group_blocks)


if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MapWidget()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, this did it for me. Is there any reason why one has to rely on this "hack"? As far as I understand it, you basically put the right group widget in a different line in order to achieve the desired layout. Do you know why the QGraphicsScene  behaves this way once you put its parent widget in the same line as the left widget?